# AWS Cognito Associated with Google as an Identity Provider Doesn't Work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have a cognito user pool which is associated with an identity pool. Cognito works fine, but when i added Google as an identity provider, i don't know how it is going to work. I did all steps in the documentation.

I mean when a user sign in on my website with Google. I can get all Google credentials of the user, id_token, name, email and so on.

In my api-gateway i need an Identity token for to pass (`method.request.header.Authorization`). But when i log in with Google, it generates an id_token which i can not use for my api-gateways.

What i can do with this id_token is using `signinCallback()` and getting AWS.config.credentials; _identityId, sessionToken,  accessKeyId, thus all webIdentityCredentials of the user. But i can do nothing with all these, since i need an id_token which is generated by Cognito.

```
function signinCallback() {    

    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
        IdentityPoolId: poolId,
        Logins: {
            'accounts.google.com': id_token }
    });

    AWS.config.region = 'eu-west-1';

    // Obtain AWS credentials
    AWS.config.credentials.get(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log(AWS.config.credentials);
        }
    });
}
```

How can i generate a valid id_token with this credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must be using google auth, and that cognito option is for "google plus"

Comment: Google+ API is enabled.

Comment: here you can see how to do the oauth on google+ https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/ (I'm just saying it is google+ not google itself)

Comment: I can sign in with Google and get credentials and id_token too. With this id_token i can get user credentials (session token, refresh token, identity id and so on) of my federated identity pool too. But i need a cognito id_token to reach to my api-gateway.

Comment: after you get the credentials (tokens, identity id, etc) use them to call lambda/api gateway using something like https://github.com/mhart/aws4 library. you need to sign the calls... not sure why you need another cognito token

Comment: I think i can not explain it good. I do not get any cognito id_token. The id token which i get is of Google. I need to send a Cognito id_token with method.request.header.Authorization to my api-gateway

Comment: I see. the thing is... you don't need to do that... is not a cognito id token that you need to send there... you already have a id token from google, you then are calling cognito to get the different credentials. now, you need to use those credentials to call lambda... forget about cognito, you need to `sign the call to lambda with the credentials you already have`

Comment: What u mean is should write my own auhtorizer with a lambda function?

Comment: no... in api gateway you can select for a method to use `Auth: AWS_IAM` and it will do it automatically... but what it is internally doing is to check the sign call data... so you need to sign your calls to lambda

Comment: Im trying to write my own function. The authorization function checks if my id_token correct which i get from Google. I want to that for Cognito too. Can i check if id_token, access token or refresh token correct?

Comment: yes, you will need anyway to send the credentials to each call... using the sign process (you will need to understand how to decode them) or sending directly the credentials... and check the docs there must be a way to check them... but that is exactly what the AWS_IAM auth does... but yes you can do whatever you want really...